# XSLT- Copying certain attributes based on the value of other attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, attributes, transformation

I have the following XML sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<languages>
    <language lang='english' source='1'/>
    <language lang='english' source='2'/>
    <language lang='french' target='1' new1-fr='56' new2-fr='66'/>
    <language lang='german' target='1' new1-ger='20' new2-ger='21'/>
    <language lang='norwegian' target='2' new3-no='76' new2-no='15'/>
    <language lang='norwegian' target='1' new1-no='30'></language>
    <language lang='german' target='2' new1-ger='23' new2-ger='24' new3-ger='25'/>
</languages>
```

What I want to do is: 
when the @target of language elements (@lang=french|german|norwegian) are the same as the @source of language (@lang='english)', copy their attributes(all which start with 'new') as attributes to the element language lang='english'

This is what it should look like:

```
<languages>
    <language lang='english' source='1' new1-fr='56' new2-fr='66' new1-ger='20' new2-ger='21' new1-no='30'/>
    <language lang='english' source='2' new3-no='76' new2-no='15' new1-ger='23' new2-ger='24' new3-ger='25'/>
</languages>
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: If you're stuck on where to start, start with an [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copying), add an [xsl:key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#key) matching `language` using `@target`, add a template matching `language[@source]` that outputs the language element and applys templates to the current attributes and also the attributes of the matching keys (`key('lang',@source)/@*`). You'll probably also need to add an empty template matching what needs to be stripped (`language[@target]|language[@target]/@lang|@target`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following templates. The first one only takes care of copying the root node

```
<xsl:template match="languages">
   <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And the second one matches all `language` elements which have `@source` attributes. Then it copies the element itself before copying all attributes from the source element and the desired attributes of the `language` element whose `@target` attribute is equal to the `$src` variable - excluding the attributes with the names `lang` and `target`.

```
<xsl:template match="language[@source]">
    <xsl:variable name="src" select="@source" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@* | ../language[@target=$src]/@*[not(local-name(.) ='target') and not(local-name(.) ='lang')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already accepted an answer without showing what you tried, I'll go ahead and add this alternative that's based on my comment...

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="lang" match="language" use="@target"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="language[@source]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|key('lang',@source)/@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="language[@target]|language[@target]/@lang|@target"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQf2